# Does difficulty target remains static for 2016 blocks in Bitcoin?

Tags: difficulty

I know that in Bitcoin the difficulty target adjust after creating 2016 blocks. So, it means that within these 2016 block the difficulty target remains same (static). Am I correct?

If this is correct then the miners has to find the right Hash of the header. Header=version+hash of previous blockheader+merkle tree root+timestamp+difficulty target+nonce variable.

Now, it seems that within these 2016 blocks the *input* (block header) to the hash function will be different but the *output* (difficulty target) remains the same. Therefore it seems to me that it breaks the property of "strong collision resistance" property of the hash. Am I correct? In other word, Bitcoin uses this property of the hash function to make it difficult to find solution of the puzzle.

Comment: OK. it does [not] breaks the property of "strong collision resistance" property because the  output of the hash function can be less than the target value.

Comment: May I remind downvoters that they *must* provide a reason why they downvoted and if they vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

The target is adjusted every 2016 blocks but the hash of mined blocks does not have to equal the target. For the block to be valid, its hash must be *less than or equal to* the target.

So in that run of 2016 blocks, each block has a different output from the hash function. All are less than the target.

I imagine that it is incredibly unlikely that any block hash has ever exactly equalled the target.

Comment: Does difficulty target remains static for 2016 blocks in Bitcoin?

Comment: Yes. Since it is only recalculated every 2016 blocks, for those 2016 blocks the target is static / unchanging / the same / a constant / invariant.